# Deep-linking on xcode 11 beta5 and swiftui

Tags: deep-linking, swiftui, xcode11

I wanted to play a bit with SwiftUI and deep-linking, with passing data between two apps. But it seems not to work.

I build two small apps. First app with a textfield and a button, second app with a label and a button. When I press the button in the first app, it calls the second app via the given url scheme and vice versa.

First App looks like that...

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var message: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        Group {

            TextField("Enter message...", text: $message).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder).padding()

            Button(action: {
                // go to second app

                let application = UIApplication.shared
                let secondAppPath = "second://\(self.message)"
                let appUrl = URL(string: secondAppPath)!

                application.open(appUrl, options: [ : ], completionHandler: nil)

                }) { Text("Go to second app")}
                .padding()
                .border(Color.black, width: 2)
        }
    }
}
```

and the info.plist...

```xml
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>second</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>first</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Second app info.plist

```xml
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>first</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>second</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And when I press the button in the first app, this function in the second app should print the url like: "second://somethingfromthetextfield"

```swift
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print(url)

    return true
}
```

But its not doing it. The second app starts but didn't print anything. Now i wondering, am I doing something wrong? Is it working anyways on Xcode beta and SwiftUI or does it work differently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method 'application:openURL:options:' is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624786/method-applicationopenurloptions-is-not-called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following method in the SceneDelegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    print("\(URLContexts.first!.url)")
}
```