# Method 'application:openURL:options:' is not called

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, custom-scheme-url

I'm trying to open my app from a web page using custom schemes. The app is opened but the following method is not called:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // This is not called
}
```

My `info.plist` looks like the following:

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>MyApp</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>url here</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

The project is created with Xcode 11.1, and I'm testing on iOS 13.

Comment: Are you on iOS13?

Comment: yeap. does it matter?

Comment: If you have an iOS 13 app it’s the SceneDelegate methods that are called.

Comment: yes i do... i will check and let u know, please post like an answer...

Comment: Yes, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624477/application-urloptions-is-never-called) Q&A

Comment: Check my answer on this question the solution is same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62842100/how-check-data-from-today-widget/64534139#64534139

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Implement `scene(_:openURLContexts:)` in your scene delegate.

If the URL launches your app, you will get `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` instead and it’s in the `options`.

Comment: I was wondering why below method was not called. 

application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

Comment: Can you answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973143/opening-app-using-custom-url-scheme-first-time-scene-openurlcontexts-does-n

Comment: This was the tip for me. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate how to achieve it in `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`? Thanks.

Comment: @matt I was just hoping maybe you could provide a code snippet here:)

Comment: In my case none of these methods are being called, neither scene(_:openURLContexts:) nor scene(_:willConnectTo:options:).

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry With a project created before Xcode 11, they would not be.

Comment: my xcode is latest, 11.3.1. The other method scene( userActivity) is calling but only when app is in background, but when its not in background none of the methods is calling.

Comment: Will every active scene be called or does the OS just pick one?

Comment: What if I'm currently working in Xcode 10. Does that mean openURL willnot be called at all in iOS 13+ ??

Comment: Thanks for the solution first of all. It took time to understand that `scene(_:openURLContexts:)` called when the app is loaded and presented in apps stack. But if the app IS CLOSED, conforms to some type and called from another app, `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` is being called instead of `openURLContexts` method.

Answer (score 28):

> Here is the method in SceneDelegate.swift. Swift version For **iOS13**

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    if let url = URLContexts.first?.url {
        // Handle URL
        WXApi.handleOpen(url, delegate: AppDelegate.shared)
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain "WXApi" and try to give a more generic example.

Comment: WXApi here is Wechat API to Open the url in WeChat

Answer (score 24):

With the latest SDK, this does work fine if you are at NOT using SceneDelegate.

If you are using sceneDelegate the the following AppDelegate method is not called and therefore the login cannot be handled.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handled = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        application,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
        annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    return handled
}
```

This is because, this method is (understandably) deferred to the following method in the SceneDelegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    ...
}
```

The solution which I can confirm as working for iOS 13 applications implementing a SceneDelegate is:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }
    let _ = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        UIApplication.shared,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: nil,
        annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])        
}
```

Answer (score 20):

**iOS 14 and above** 
For SwiftUI apps
*Note: This method handles the reception of Universal Links*

`public func onOpenURL(perform action: @escaping (URL) -> ()) -> some View`

```
@main
MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: handleURL)
        }
    }

    func handleURL(_ url: URL) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I've been searching for this for hours. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: It is not worked when app is closed, only if app is in background. Add DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500)) {...} inside .onOpenUrl to fix this

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Matt there This is how I solve the problem.

on SceneDelegate.m

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {

    NSURL *url = connectionOptions.URLContexts.allObjects.firstObject.URL;
    NSLog(@"When app is not on memory  ::::: %@",url);

}

​
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene openURLContexts:(NSSet *)URLContexts {

    NSURL *url = URLContexts.allObjects.firstObject.URL;    
    NSLog(@"When app is on memory ::::: %@",url);

}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. I have posted here. Could you answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973143/opening-app-using-custom-url-scheme-first-time-scene-openurlcontexts-does-n

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and neither `scene(_ scene:, continue userActivity:)` nor `scene(_ scene:, openURLContexts URLContexts:)` was called.

When I checked the `connectionOptions` passed to the method `scene(_ scene:, willConnectTo session, options connectionOptions:)` it had a user activity with the expected URL. So, I ended up calling the method manually:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene,
           willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
           options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first {
        self.scene(scene, continue: userActivity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem, using safari shortcut to start the application, openURLContexts callback multiple times.

```
2019-12-09 18:33:41.257088+0800 OCTEST[5019:1468254] openURLContextsopenURLContexts {(
    <UIOpenURLContext: 0x2805a71c0; URL: appoctest://action=123123123; options: <UISceneOpenURLOptions: 0x280bd4750; sourceApp: (null); annotation: (null); openInPlace: NO>>
)}
2019-12-09 18:33:42.022132+0800 OCTEST[5019:1468254] openURLContextsopenURLContexts {(
    <UIOpenURLContext: 0x2805a6d40; URL: appoctest://action=123123123; options: <UISceneOpenURLOptions: 0x280bd6f70; sourceApp: (null); annotation: (null); openInPlace: NO>>
)}
```