# openURL not being called when I launch the app from Scheme Url (Swift project)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I open my application through `myapp://param1=abc` the open url function is not called.

I've added functions `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to make it `true`, as the Apple documentation says, but it's still not called. The application opens perfectly, but not calling the function open url I can not get the param1

This is my `AppDelegate` file:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate  {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        // Here doesn't come! :(
        return true
    }


    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to check launchOptions dictionary in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions().

Comment: Have you added the urlScheme in info.plist?

Comment: @Jitendra launchOption dictionary in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() is nil.

Comment: @PGDev I added urlScheme in info.plist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method 'application:openURL:options:' is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624786/method-applicationopenurloptions-is-not-called)

Answer (score 4):

The signature of `openUrl` method in `AppDelegate` is updated to,

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

You need to add your `urlScheme` in the **URL Types** under **Info** tab in project settings, i.e.

[image]

---

**For Swift-5 and iOS-13:**

In `SceneDelegate.swift` file, you need to implement the below method to handle `urlSchemes`, i.e.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    print(URLContexts)
}
```

Comment: I had already added my urlSchema. The URL opens the application well but does not call the function to get the parameters

Comment: Have you tried putting the breakpoint there? Because it is working fine at my end.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, try implementing the same in a brand new project and see if it works.

Comment: I created a new project and all I did was add the openURL function and I added the url types and it doesn't work.

Comment: Open myapp:// from safari and see if it is working.

Comment: When open myapp:// from safari, the app opens but open url function not called

Comment: Which iOS and Swift version are you using?

Comment: ios13 and swift 5

Comment: Updated the answer for Swift-5 and iOS-13.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 14 you can use deep links instead:

```
struct ShapifyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    //Whatever you need to do goes here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So many thanks to you that this is the only correct answer for me that resolved why my application method is not being called. Days wasted.

Answer (score 0):

`application(_ application: UIApplication, open url` will not call at the time of app launch. you need to access the `launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]` and your url with the help of `[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url]`

Here is the snippet that might help you

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let url = launchOptions![UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url]
        ...

        return true
    }
```

Comment: launchOptions is always nil

Comment: any update on this? I see the same issue; open url handler doesn't get called at the time of app launch and also the launchOptions are nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the launch URL as follows:

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
  if let url = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first {
     ...
  }
}
```