# How check data from today widget

Tags: ios, swift

in ios 12 I send a url from my today widget

> self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: nil)

that receives it in the following method on appdelegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
   //code
}
```

however in ios 13 the method is never called. I read what you could do with Scenedelegate and implement the following methods

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
   //code
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
   //code
}
```

but they are never called either. As I mentioned in ios 12 I have no problem but I wanted to know if you could tell me if I am missing something to make it work in ios 13

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger "**func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {}**" method first you need to delete SceneDelegate on both file and references on plist. Then top of AppDelegate add "**var window: UIWindow?**" top of class like below. It'll work.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // Code
}
```